# How to remove object from Array in ReactJS after click event

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, javascript-objects

I'm building little app in React and I have a problem to remove and object from Array after I click on icon.

I have form with inputs and when user fill this inputs and click on a button then inputs will into an array. I have array in a state and the default is empty array.

```
const [attendees, setAttendees] = useState([]);
```

I have a function for delete a object from array after I click on icon

```
const deleteAttendee = (attendee) => {
    setAttendees({
      attendees: attendees.filter(
        (element) => element.firstName !== attendee.firstName
      ),
    });
  };
```

but there is a problem when I clicked on icon I get an error. That map is not a function.

I have in another component **map function** for rendering each user from the inputs

```
<div className="attendee-container">
      {attendees.map((_attendee, index) => {
        return (
          <div key={index}>
            <div onClick={() => deleteAttendee(_attendee)}>{trashAltIcon}</div>
            <h3>
              {index + 1}. {_attendee.firstName} {_attendee.lastName} (
              {_attendee.age})
            </h3>
          </div>
        );
      })}
    </div>
```

Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using setState you pass in the full state object like you'r doing. However when using useState hooks the setState functions takes in just that value.

Check out these [docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html#updating-state) for understanding the difference between setState and updating state with useState hook

setAttendees takes in an array so your handler should be

```
const deleteAttendee = (attendee) => {
   //Pass in filtered array as new state for attendees
   setAttendees( attendees.filter((element) => element.firstName !== attendee.firstName);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

setAttendees comes with a parameter that allows you to have the previous state.

### Here's what I did to your deleteAttendee function

```
const deleteAttendee = (event) => {

   const attendeeId = event.target.dataset.id;

   setAttendees((previousState) => previousState.filter((attendee) => attendee.id !== attendeeId))

};
```

I am using the previous state and updating that instead and instead of removing the first name I am instead removing matching ids

### Here's what the jsx looks like

```
return (
<div className="App">
  {attendees.map((_attendee, index) => {
    return (
      <div key={_attendee.id}>
        <div data-id={_attendee.id} onClick={(event) => deleteAttendee(event)}>trash</div>
        <h3>
          {index + 1}. {_attendee.firstName} {_attendee.lastName} (
          {_attendee.age})
        </h3>
      </div>
    );
  })}
</div>
```

);

I am using a data-id attribute so whenever the user clicks on the trash icon, I can pass that event into the deleteAttendee, get the value from the attribute and filter the array out if it matches. I made this change because I saw that you was filtering based on names, what if two attendees had the same name?

### Initial state of attendees

```
const [attendees, setAttendees] = useState([
   {
     id: 'tskdh3-3dfdgg-23ds-23dfsdd-2332',
     firstName: 'bob',
     lastName: 'jeo',
     age: 73
  },
  {
     id: 't3-3dfdgg-23ds-23dfsdd-2332',
     firstName: 'bob',
     lastName: 'woah',
     age: 43
  },
  {
     id: 'bsd233-33dfg-3ds-2f3fsdd-2dfdf',
     firstName: 'bob',
     lastName: 'yum',
     age: 23
   }
]);
```

For random ids to be generated, you an use an npm package called uuid, it generates unique ids.